# ¿Cómo guardar varios registros al mismo tiempo?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Soy nuevo usando `python` el framework que utilizo es `flask`,
estoy creando un sistema de control académico, pero no sé cómo agregar notas para diferentes estudiantes al mismo tiempo en `mysql`, este es el código que tengo en `Python`, pero no me funciona.
Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

```
@app.route("/guardar_notas", methods=["POST","GET"])
def guardar_notas():

if (notas is not None):
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO notas(notas,notas.alumnos_idalumnos,notas.cursos_idcursos,notas.rangos_idrangos,notas.clases_idclases,promedio)SELECT notas,notas.alumnos_idalumnos,notas.cursos_idcursos,notas.rangos_idrangos,notas.clases_idclases,promedio FROM notas  INNER JOIN alumnos ON notas.alumnos_idalumnos=alumnos.idalumnos  INNER JOIN cursos on notas.cursos_idcursos=cursos.idcursos INNER JOIN rangos ON notas.rangos_idrangos= rangos.idrangos INNER JOIN clases ON notas.clases_idclases=clases.idclases; VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(notas,promedio,alumnos_idalumnos,cursos_idcursos,rangos_idrangos,clases_idclases))
        cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        flash("NOTAS REGISTRADAS EXITOSAMENTE","success")
    else:
        flash("ERROR NO SE REGISTRARON LAS NOTAS","danger")

        return redirect(url_for('agregar_notas'))
```

También esta es la tabla de my base en `mysql`, la tabla **notas** está relacionada con (alumnos,clases,curso y rango).

```
idnotas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  notas` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
  promedio` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
  clases_idclases` int(11) NOT NULL,
  cursos_idcursos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  alumnos_idalumnos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  rangos_idrangos` int(11) NOT NULL
```

Adjunto la imagen del formulario que tengo:

[image: AQUI TENGO EL FORM PARA AGREGAR LAS NOTAS]

Comment: Puede servirte de ayuda que veas `executemany()`. En esta página hay un ejemplo https://thepythonguru.com/inserting-rows/. Espero te sea útil

Comment: estoy usando Flask y mysql y tengo el mismo inconveniente, no sé como realizar la inserción de varios datos al mismo tiempo.
Cualquier ayuda les agradezco.

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que deseas ingresar varias filas debe usar el executeMany y enviarle una lista de tuplas, algo así:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO notas(notas,notas.alumnos_idalumnos,notas.cursos_idcursos,notas.rangos_idrangos,notas.clases_idclases,promedio)SELECT notas,notas.alumnos_idalumnos,notas.cursos_idcursos,notas.rangos_idrangos,notas.clases_idclases,promedio FROM notas  INNER JOIN alumnos ON notas.alumnos_idalumnos=alumnos.idalumno`introducir el código aquí`s  INNER JOIN cursos on notas.cursos_idcursos=cursos.idcursos INNER JOIN rangos ON notas.rangos_idrangos= rangos.idrangos INNER JOIN clases ON notas.clases_idclases=clases.idclases; VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",[(notas,promedio,alumnos_idalumnos,cursos_idcursos,rangos_idrangos,clases_idclases),(notas,promedio,alumnos_idalumnos,cursos_idcursos,rangos_idrangos,clases_idclases)])
    cur.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: segui sus consejos pero no me guarda en mi base de datos

Comment: ¿Verificaste tambien que todo el query este correcto? Hay ocasiones que el query esta incorrecto y el python no indica el error ( o que le mandas data incorrecta en los parametros)

Comment: si ya verifique y lo cambie ahora utilizo solo esto `db.execute("INSERT INTO asistencias(fecha,faltas,atrasos,asistencia,alumnos_idalumnos) VALUES(:fecha_fin,:faltas,:atrasos,:asistencia,:alumnos_idalumnos)",
    {"fecha_fin":fecha_fin,"faltas":faltas,"atrasos":atrasos,"asistencia":asistencia,"alumnos_idalumnos":alumnos_idalumnos})
   db.commit()`    funciona pero solo me guarda el primer dato no todos los datos y ahora es lo mismo quiero agregar asistencias de varios alumnos al mismo tiempo

Comment: ¿Tienes de pronto el error que sale al ejecutarlo con executemany?

Comment: mmuchas gracias ya pude arreglarlo